# Can't create order in back end! Google couldn't help

Tags: backend, shipping-methods, create-order

I was just testing a new extension, and was trying to create an order and when I click on shipping method, nothing comes up. So I assumed it was the problem of the extension so I deactivate it in xml under the modules folder and disable it in Advanced under configuration. I even tried to uninstall it and disable other extension as well, but it still does the same thing, when I refresh the Create New Order page, an error message shows up under the shipping method section. Everything works fine on the front end

Fatal error: Call to a member function setTemplate() on a non-object in /home/content/76/11974576/html/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/sales/order/create/shipping/method/form.phtml on line 67

Much appreciated if anyone can help, this is driving me crazy!

[Please click here to see the back end error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ObOB.png)

Comment: Did you clear your cache?

Comment: Yes, a thousand times =[

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the extension from http://www.freegento.com/ddl-magento-extension.php and remove and compare with this to you current installation an remove all the files associated with the extension. My guess is you have left an xml file of the extension and also check for the form.phtml file in the mentioned directory. If it does not exist there, please copy it from a default magento package.

Comment: Dont forget to update us after :)

Comment: Yes, the line of code is from an old extension which I have replace with the new extension, that's why it is causing the problem. I didn't know extension would rewrite core files. Big lesson. Thank you anyway!

Comment: If my answer helped you, could you mark it